Trying to run a python script that uses the 'requests' module in on windows 10
I'm having the following error produced every time I try to run the grabber.py script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\dolgi\Downloads\export\grabber.py", line 1, in <module>
        import requests
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

My first thought was I didn't have the requests module installed but I checked and do that that installed.
C:\Users\dolgi\Downloads\export>pip show requests
Name: requests
Version: 2.32.3
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache-2.0
Location: C:\Users\dolgi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages
Requires: certifi, charset-normalizer, idna, urllib3
Required-by:


I'm guessing that you have two different installations of Python on your computer.  The requests module is installed for one of them, but you're using the other to run the code.

Please edit the question and add two things: the exact command you use to run the code, and the output of this short script import sys; print(sys.path)

You might have multiple versions of Python installed on your system, and pip might have installed the requests module for a different Python version than the one you're using to run your script.
To check if this is the case, you can run:
python --version
python3 --version

To make sure both commands point to the same Python version.
You can try explicitly installing the requests module for the version of Python you are using to run the script.
python -m pip install requests
python3 -m pip install requests

If this not work
Sometimes, simply reinstalling the requests package can resolve this issue. Uninstall and then reinstall the package:
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests


You can also use a virtual environment which will basically eliminate this problem: as long as you install requests on the venv and run your python script with the same venv, it doesn't really matter what Python version you're using (unless, of course, you want to run your script with a specific version).
